# AnyConnect cannot confirm it is connected to your secure gateway

Tags: cisco-anyconnect

I still got error from the title after copying my local profile and user preferences file.

Most of the instructions told to untick the "Block connections to untrusted networks" from the UI settings (little gear icon), in the Preferences tab.

But there is no such checkbox on the newly installed AnyConnect UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to modify in the ProgramData the AnyConnectLocalPolicy.xml so that the StrictCertificateTrust to be false:

```
<StrictCertificateTrust>false</StrictCertificateTrust>
```

This made it possible to connect in the first place.